# Why is the toolbar containing the screenshot icon missing in uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, sdk, appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

Normally there is a toolbar in uiautomatorviewer that contains call-to-action icons like taking screenshots, saving screenshots etc. Somehow that toolbar is missing in my uiautomatorviewer. I am opening it for the first time after installing Android/SDK on macOS, so as it is, I can't capture screenshots from a connected mobile device.

This is what I see:

[image]

I should see something like this:

[image]

How can I get the toolbar? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is seen in newer version of macOS.
So download this jar file
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.16-202006040540/swt-4.16-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip

after downloading and rename swt.jar file to swt2.jar and copy the file and paste it in Andriod/sdk/lib/x_86 folder